# Search array, and if found

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_number] => 1000000002
            [quantity] => 1
            [size] => L
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_number] => 1000000002
            [quantity] => 1
            [size] => XS
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_number] => 1000000002
            [quantity] => 1
            [size] => M
        )

)
```

Hello guys,

I need some help with this. I am creating a shop system.
And i am trying to add products to a basket/cart.

I need to check if the product number is in the array, if yes? then is the size the right one? - if yes, then update the right one..

if the size is not the right add a new.

If the product number isn't in the array .. add a new

I have tryed with in_array, foreach, and some stuff.. i cant get it to work. Can any of you help me ?

it is in php

Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Tell us what language and post your attempted code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my implementation:

```
$ShoppingBasket = Array
(
     Array
        (
            "product_number" => 1000000002,
            "quantity" => 1,
            "size" => "L"
        ),
    Array
        (
            "product_number" => 1000000002,
            "quantity" => 1,
            "size" => "XS"
        ),
    Array
        (
            "product_number" => 1000000002,
            "quantity" => 1,
            "size" => "M"
        )

);

function addItem(&$ShoppingBasket, $PN, $size) 
{ //use references with & to modify the array directly 
    // loop through each element of your array (mind this is an array of hashes.
    foreach ($ShoppingBasket as &$item) //reference again so it modifies the item direclty in $ShoppingBasket.
    {
        // compare if the PN and size are the same 
        if ($item["product_number"] == $PN && strcmp($item["size"],$size) == 0)
        {
                $item["quantity"] ++; //increase the quantity count
                return; //end the function if we found the item.
        }
    }
    // this acts as a else close, it only executes if we haven't found anything already.
    // push a new hash in $ShoppingBasket where all the field are specified.
    array_push($ShoppingBasket, array("product_number" => $PN,"quantity" => 1,"size" => $size));
    return;
}
function removeItem(&$ShoppingBasket, $PN, $size) 
{ //use references with & to modify the array directly 
    for($i = 0 ; $i < count($ShoppingBasket) ; $i++) 
    {//need to interate with a counter to have the position in the array
        if ($ShoppingBasket[$i]["product_number"] == $PN && strcmp($ShoppingBasket[$i]["size"],$size) == 0)
        {
               array_splice($ShoppingBasket, $i, 1);
               //splice removes 1 element from position $i
               return TRUE; //we have removed something
        }
    }
    return FALSE; // we have not removed the item
}

//little test of the function
addItem($ShoppingBasket,1000000002, "M");
addItem($ShoppingBasket,1000000002, "M");
addItem($ShoppingBasket,1000000002, "XXL");
addItem($ShoppingBasket,1000000232, "M");
print_r($ShoppingBasket);
removeItem($ShoppingBasket,1000000232, "M");
removeItem($ShoppingBasket,1000000002, "M");
removeItem($ShoppingBasket,1000000002, "XXL");
print_r($ShoppingBasket);
```

Comment: i dont know how to thanks you!

I used .. 6 hours now .. i think.. trying to sovle this.. 

Can i ask you to explain the code for me ? - So i learn some new stuff ?

Comment: I'm almost crying now! :D

Comment: I have commented the code. If you still struggle to understand I would guess you are a bit new to PHP. Don't worry you will get it with practice.

Comment: Cool m8, i understand, what i did wrong now :) .. THANKS a lot! 

How come i cant put in mysqli_query into the function? i'll like to update my tabel in db too when updating the array...

Comment: is it possible to make removeItme too ? :)

Comment: I have added a remove function with some comments. The SQL query is another subject which is a bit more complicated. You will need to do some research on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have the ability to do this, but if you do you could try the following. Key your array by your product number and use the array_key_exists() function to determine if that key is present.

```
if( array_key_exists( $product_number, $product_array ) )
{
    //
    // The product number was found in the array of products
    //
}

else
{
    //
    // The product number was not found in the array of products
    //
}
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: Well you can perform another check because then you'll be able to easily access your product - if( $product_array[ $product_number ]['size'] == '' ) {}